# How to base a style on another style in a resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have a theme that is applied to all buttons in a resource dictionary. Now I want to add a trigger to the button while inheriting the style changes from the dictionary. I tried the following code, but it says that the control cannot be found. How can I fix it ?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

      <conv:ErrorContentConverter x:Key="ErrorContentConverter" />

      <Style x:Key="ValidTrigger" 
             TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="False">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>   
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The base template:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" 
            Value="{DynamicResource NuclearButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF042271" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />

    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Give your base Style a name, say FooStyle.

In the example you gave, modify the TargetType and BasedOn to look as follows:

```
 <Style x:Key="ValidTrigger" 
        TargetType="{x:Type Control}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can I do it without assigning a name? There is only one style for the control in the dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean that, rather than assign a key to the base style, you would like the extended style to figure out which style to extend based on it's TargetType? I don't know.

Comment: Why do you hesitate to give the base style an x:Key="FooStyle" ?

Comment: @PieterMüller: If you assign a key to the style, the style is no longer used by default by all matching controls within the context. Nathan Friend's answer provides a solution for this. I just got the same problem :)

Answer (score 36):

One trick I've used in the past:  in your `ResourceDictionary` that defines blanket styles for your application, add an `x:Key` to the style you'd like to inherit from, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
  <!-- your style here -->
</Style>
```

To apply this style to all controls of the specified type (`Button` in this example) without having to explicitly set the `Style` attribute of every `Button`, add another style that's `BasedOn` this style, but doesn't have a key:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

Using this method, all `Button`s in your application will automatically inherit your custom style, but you can still create additional styles `BasedOn` the `ButtonStyle` entry and avoid blowing away all of your custom styling.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no base style defined for "control" so your 
`BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}"` part won't find anything.

You probably want to change

```
<Style x:Key="ValidTrigger" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" >
```

to

```
<Style x:Key="ValidTrigger" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" >
```